# Java game uses a thread to move things on screen, slows down

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics

I'm working on a simple "ping-pong" 2d game in java.

(My previous question regarding this involved a timer. I've changed it to a thread, which is a different topic so I thought it would be suitable to make a new question).

The game uses a thread that runs all the time, in order to move objects on the screen, and repaint it constantly.

I've added some code to the thread to ensure that the game runs at constant speed, but that doesn't seem to work.

At the first few seconds of the game, it's always really fast (the "ping pong ball" flies really fast), and then it suddenly slows down, to a speed that seems pretty constant.

Why is this happening? Here's the code of the `run()` method of the `Runnable`:

```
public void run(){

        beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(true){

            bPaddle.move();
            tPaddle.move();
            ball.move();
            checkCollision();
            checkInScreen();

            repaint();

            timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeTime;
            sleep = 5 - timeDiff;

            System.out.println(sleep);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleep);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Not sure this is relevant, but when the code takes longer than 5ms, `sleep` will be negative... Have you tried a higher base value for sleep? Even 20 will result in 50 frames per second.

Comment: In that case, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO you shouldn't rely on 'sleep' methods in a 'realtime' game.

What you should do instead is:

1. Define your velocities bound to a time-span. (Lets say any velocity you have means that this is the amount of units the entity should move in 1000ms). E.g. Your ball moves 10px in 1000ms.
2. Each time your loop starts another round, calculate the time difference when the loop ran the last time.
3. Lets say the previous loop-run (after a heavy lag) lies 500ms in the past.
4. You calculate time percentage: 500ms / 1000ms  * 100 = 50%
5. Apply the time percentage to each time-dependent action. E.g. for moving the ball: 10px * 0.5 = 5px. Means: Move your ball this frame by 5px.

Same with any other stuff in your game which depends on time!

Using this 'thinking' you will make your engine 'cpu-speed independet' and it will run (basicly) the same on any machine. (Don't quote me on that :P)

The only time (imho) a sleep is OK, is when you want to slow down the game a bit in case it runs too fast - since you could get really small numbers...

Comment: That scaling procedure is called (Time) Delta Scaling.